# Changing the len() function in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Before, in my code I had this vector:

```
x = [
[0.72,0.82],
[0.91,-0.69],
[0.03,0.93],
[0.12,0.25],
[0.96,0.47],
[0.8,-0.75]
]
```

And there was this **for** that worked correctly:

```
for k in range(1,10):

    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        sum = 0

        for j in range(0,len(x[i])):
            sum += x[i][j] * w[j]
```

I have to make a change in the vector:

```
x = [
[0.72,0.82,-1],
[0.91,-0.69,-1],
[0.03,0.93,-1],
[0.12,0.25,-1],
[0.96,0.47,-1],
[0.8,-0.75,-1]
]
```

In this sense, I realize that I need to make a modification in my **len(x[i])** so that the previous result is the same as now, I tried to **len(x[0][1])**, but it did not work, what could I do?

Comment: What "did not work" specifically? And why does the code even need to change?

Comment: Why do you need to make a change to `len()`? The whole point of `range(len())` is that it gives a dynamic range based on the actual length. If you want to cut it short by one element, `range(len(something)-1)`

Comment: Why not just loop directly over the rows and values? There is no need to use indices here. For the `w[j]` values, use `zip()` to pair up the row in `x` with `w`.

Comment: `for row in x:`, `total = sum(col * wj for (col, wj) in zip(row, w))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just have j go from 0 to 1 then.  (or if you want, "len(x[i]) - 1")

```
for k in range(1,10):

    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        sum = 0

        for j in range(2):
            sum += x[i][j] * w[j]
```